# How to use for loop in JSON in API use php

Tags: php, json, api

here is php code in which i am getting data from the api, All working well but i am trapped in for loop. When i am using constant value .i.e 10 in loop, it shows only 10 data, but i want to use variable on the place of constant, so that it will display all data.

```
<?php  
$number = 10;
for ($i=0; $i <= $number  ; $i++) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['SerialNo']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['StationName'];  ?></td>

        <td><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['ScheduleArrival'];  ?> / <?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['ScheduleDeparture']; ?></td>

        <td class="train-mobile"><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['ActualArrival'];  ?> / <?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['ActualDeparture'];  ?></td>

        <td class="train-mobile"><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['Day'];  ?></td>
        <td style="color: red;"><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['DelayInDeparture']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php  }  ?>
```

Comment: i want something more in it...

Comment: i want to insert the following condition

Comment: <td style="color: green;">
                                        
                                        <?php 
                                        if ( $json['TrainRoute']['StationName'] = $json['CurrentStation']['StationName'] ) {
                                                echo $json['CurrentStation']['StationName'];
                                        }
                                        
                                         ?>
                                        
                                
                                    </td>

Comment: inside the above table

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($json['TrainRoute']); $i++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['SerialNo']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['StationName'];  ?></td>

            <td><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['ScheduleArrival'];  ?> / <?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['ScheduleDeparture']; ?></td>

            <td class="train-mobile"><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['ActualArrival'];  ?> / <?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['ActualDeparture'];  ?></td>

            <td class="train-mobile"><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['Day'];  ?></td>
            <td style="color: red;"><?php echo $json['TrainRoute'][$i]['DelayInDeparture']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php  }  ?>
```

Comment: If solution is works then please mark as correct/upvote then future user easily find out correct answer